# ubuntu - upload csv file using mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to upload a `csv` file to a `mysql` table and it keep giving me an error.  I am in `mysql` using the database I want to upload the file.  I've tried two queries at the command line.

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL  '/home/susan/ahref.csv' replace INTO TABLE ahrefRealtor FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I get this error

```
  LOAD DATA linkProfile '/home/susan/ahref.csv' replace INTO TABLE ahrefRealtor;
  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'linkProfile '/home/susan/ahref.csv' replace INTO TABLE ahrefRealtor' at line 1
```

2nd query

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL  '/home/susan/ahref.csv' replace INTO TABLE ahrefRealtor FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Same error

Comment: You should ask on [stack-overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), you would have more chances to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the `INFILE` keyword - the syntax should be something like

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './table1.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE table1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Also, `LOAD DATA LOCAL` is likely disabled by default - although you should be able to enable it explicitly on the mysql client command line using the `--local-infile` option i.e.

```
$ mysql -u root -p test --local-infile
Enter password: 

mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-----------+--------+
| Id | name      | value  |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | "Alice"   | 12.345 |
|  2 | "Bob"     | 34.560 |
|  3 | "Carol"   | 89.100 |
+----+-----------+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './table1.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE table1 
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;
+----+-----------+--------+
| Id | name      | value  |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | "Alice"   | 12.345 |
|  2 | "Bob"     | 34.560 |
|  3 | "Charlie" | 33.330 |
|  4 | "Drew"    | 42.000 |
|  5 | "Edward"  |  0.100 |
+----+-----------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting the quote characters in your output table. You may want the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` specifier too.